# Using a for loop to append $i to element names

Tags: php, loops, variables

I have this PHP array:

```
[parent] => stdClass Object (
    [child_1] => {
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Steve
    }

    [child_2] => {
        [id] => 5
        [name] => Mike
    }

    [child_3] => {
        [id] => 7
        [name] => Bob
    }
}
```

There are an unlimited number of children so I need to loop over them to insert them in the database. Since there is nothing to foreach over, how do I append $i to the variable names in a for loop?

I would like to do:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $child = ${"parent->child_" . $i};  
}
```

But I get the error: Undefined variable $parent->child_1.

However if I echo out $parent->child_1; normally it works.

I also tried $child = "parent->child_" . $i; and echo'd $$child; but same error.

What is the proper way to access the child elements?

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object. Don't you see `stdClass Object` at the beginning?

Comment: `$parent->{"child_" . $i}`

Comment: `$child = $array['parent']->{"child_$i"};`

Comment: yeah sorry, object.

Comment: You don't need to access the properties by name to begin with here, a StdClass object can be iterated over using foreach. `foreach($parent as $child) { ... }`